# Azure ARM - List keys - How to fetch key value of a specific key?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net, azure-iot-hub, azure-resource-group

I have setup an Azure IOThub using Azure resource management template. I need to to get the "shared access policy" - 'iothubowner' 's primarykey value and use it for the setup of another resource downstream.

I am able to fetch all the shared access policies and their respective primary keys as an array / object using the listkeys function in the Azure ARM template json as below

```
"outputs": {
    "IoT_hub_ownerkey1": {
      "value": "[listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs',variables('vHubName')),'2016-02-03').value]",
      "type": "array"
    }
  }
```

which results in

```
      Name             Type                       Value     
  ===============  =========================  ==========
    ioT_hub_ownerkey1  Array                      [
    {
      "keyName": "iothubowner",
      "primaryKey": "mKAQTt9U5XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "secondaryKey": "DpFgimzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "rights": "RegistryWrite, ServiceConnect, DeviceConnect"
    },
    {
      "keyName": "service",
      "primaryKey": "hrsK7laMIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "secondaryKey": "omm3RTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "rights": "ServiceConnect"
    },
    {
      "keyName": "device",
      "primaryKey": "sfE9QbhLDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "secondaryKey": "v5Oyw3XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "rights": "DeviceConnect"
    },
```

....
      ]

**I need to know how to filter only the primarykey of the "iothubowner" policy ?**

i tried this but got error

```
"IoT_hub_ownerkey2": {
  "value": "[listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs',variables('vHubName')),'2016-02-03').value.keyName['iothubowner'].primaryKey]",
  "type": "string"
}
```

**Error**

```
    {
      "code": "DeploymentOutputEvaluationFailed",
      "target": "IoT_hub_ownerkey2",
      "message": "The template output 'IoT_hub_ownerkey2' is not valid: Template language expression property 'keyName' has an invalid array index. Please 
see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.."
    }
```

Comment: I am able use the absolute index of the array '0' (since iothubowner' always comes in as first in the array) to fetch the primary key od iothubowner... But it would be nice to filter based on the name of the shared access policy instead of index

"IoT_hub_ownerkey1": {
      "value": "[listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs',variables('vHubName')),'2016-02-03').value[0].primaryKey]",
      "type": "string"
    },

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I did to output the primary key for the 'iothubowner' from my ARM template:

```
"outputs": {
    "IotHubKey": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs/Iothubkeys', variables('iotHubName'), 'iothubowner'), '2016-02-03').primaryKey]"
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps :)